# to solve using minimum if else

Tags: java, logic

Okay guys,I need to solve this problem using minimum if else condition.Let me explain my problem.
Suppose there are three String city,state and country.I need to print it in following format

```
city,state,country
```

In case if city="" then it needs to be

```
state,country
```

In case if state="" the it needs to be

```
 city,country
```

if country="" then

```
city,state
```

if all string are"" then nothing should be printed or just a "".
and every other possible conditions.Those three strings may have value or may contain "" not null.So using least if else condition i need to solve this problem.
**Note:Not a homework.**

Comment: What if all of them are `""`?

Comment: What did you try? When would you want to show the comma[s]?

Comment: commas are necessary.It is in requirement

Comment: You are solving a wrong problem or this is a homework.

Comment: try this:  (city+","+state+","+country).replace(",,",",").replaceAll("^,|,$", "");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
for (String s: new String [] {city, state, country})
{
    if (!s.isEmpty ())
    {
        if (sb.length () > 0) sb.append (",");
        sb.append (s);
    }
}
System.out.println (sb);
```

Comment: You beat me to it! This is the best solution.

Comment: doesnot seem to work if state and country is empty but you have city only.Prints city,,

Comment: Oh.  My fault.  Fixed.

Comment: Why you guys do others home work :) ,,nice solution !

Comment: For reputation, I guess...

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov:thnks man.And its not a homework.This will be implemented in my company project where i am working as a trainee.Thnks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the following way:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append((city.isEmpty() ? "" : city + ","))
       .append(((state.isEmpty() ? "" : state + ",")))
       .append(((country.isEmpty() ? "" : country)));
String result = builder.toString();
if (result.endsWith(","))
    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
System.out.println(result);
```

Not very elegant, though.

P.S. I'd use guava's `Joiner` for such task.

Comment: @Dukeling Missed it at first.

Answer (score 1):

Add them all to array or list, then use a string builder to build the output, like this (Pseudo Code):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++)
   if (!"".equals(array[i]))
      stringbuilder.append(s + ",");                   

if (sb.length() > 0)
  sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
```

Comment: will always have an extra comma at the end.

Comment: now it will crash if all three strings are empty

Comment: Your right again, fixed it again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String finalString =(city.equals("") ? "" : ("city"  + ",")) +
                    (state.equals("")? "" : ("state" + ",")) +
                    country.equals("") ? "" : "country"

finalString = finalString.endsWith(",") ? finalString.substring(0, finalString.length-1) : finalString;

System.out.println(finalString);
```

Comment: think you need parantheses `("city"  + ",") `, etc

Comment: What if `country` is empty? You'll print `city,state,` (unwanted comma at end).